# Significance of RECORD_ACTION and RECORD_IS_ROOT in TIBCO MDM

Tags: tibco, tibco-mdm

How reliable is RECORD_ACTION and RECORD_IS_ROOT in rulebase constraints? In our application, we have a couple of business requirements which are driven by these values. But recently it was noticed that there are occurrences where these variables become null during a workflow execution which leads to nullifying the entire rulebase constraint. Do we have any alternatives for these?

Answer (score 1):

`RECORD_ACTION` and `RECORD_IS_ROOT` are system variable in `TIBCO MDM`.
User does not have control on these variables.
So, will suggest to use user define attribute for any *Rulebase* operations.